# timing queries in gremlin-console

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph

I am trying to compare the response time of my queries in gremlin-console (the graph database is janusgraph, and the backend database is hbase). To do that, there is the "clock()" step, that can run the query multiple times and return the average response time.

But as stated in the documentation, there is a "warm up" phase :

> The warm up simply consists of running the query one time before
>   timing starts. This means that for a single timing iteration, the
>   human perceived time will be roughly double the time returned by the
>   clock analysis.

Because of that warm up phase, all the graph needed for the traversal is always in the cache, which will not be true in the real world.
For example, the query I am working on takes 6 minutes to complete because there is a lot of data to fetch from the hbase backend, but the clock() step display a execution time of 10s, which could only be true in the best scenario.

Is there another, better way to get a correct execution time of my queries using gremlin-console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can still use `clock()`. Just rollback the transaction between executions:

```
clock { g.V().iterate();g.tx().rollback() }
```

Comment: Yet I think it is necessary to disable the database cache with db-cache=false

Comment: I suppose it could be done that way too as a JanusGraph specific way to handle it.

Comment: Actually I think i need both : db-cache=false to disable database cache, and rollback() to empty the transaction cache between two executions

Comment: How can I do that in a browser query?

Comment: you can't do that exact function in a http call. `clock()` is a function of Gremlin Console. that said, you could do a `clock()` of http calls if you liked. it's just a matter of changing the calls inside of the clock closure.